# package-cleanup --oldkernels won't clean out an old 3.x kernel with 4.x kernel installed

Tags: centos, kernel, package-management

I think package-cleanup is getting confused and thinks only 1 kernel is installed.

Centos 7.2

I had a single 3.x kernel installed.  I then installed kernel 4.x using

```
rpm -Uvh http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-2.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm
yum --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-ml
```

I now want to get rid of the 3.x kernel (space is tight on my /boot partition)

package-cleanup reports:

```
# package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=1
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
No old kernels to remove
```

Is there any way I can make this work?

Comment: remove the 3.x kernel packages manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you have installed an ElRepo kernel. It doesn't count as a "normal" kernel, so the built-in Linux tools don't see it as a kernel. Try to run the following command to see how many official kernels are recognized.

```
rpm -q kernel
```

If you want to uninstall your previous kernel, you have to run

```
yum remove kernel
```

But be cautious :) And remember, you can't manage the elrepo kernel with the standard system tools.